# Why is are my emmet abbreviations not working with React on VSCode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, emmet

Emmet abbreviations are working with HTML, but when I try to do something like `rcc` on a Javascript file, the React abbreviation fails to show up. I have tried modifying my user settings, which currently look like this:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"files.associations": { 
    "*.js": "javascriptreact" 
}
```

Here is an image of what shows up when I type `rcc`:
[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Because your file extension should be `.jsx`

Comment: I tried changing the file to ```.jsx```, but emmet still failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: rcc is display in suggestion]

[image: rcc display this code]

install React & Redux Snippets extention see below:

[image: React & Redux Snippets extention]

Answer (score 2):

"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact"
},

Above snippet enables emmet for JS/JSX code and it should be working fine.
For react snippets using abbreviations please try below extension. I use the same for it.

ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets

Answer (score 1):

Your emmet is likely working, but abbreviations like *rcc* are from JS Snippets. I use the VS code extension **JS JSX Snippets** by sky ran.

Hope this helped.